# Where I can find the resize icon of Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, resize, icons

Sorry for the stupid question... I have a div that I can't resize using CSS3, so I'm currently using the unicode character [U+21F2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21f2/index.htm) as resize "icon". But I like the icon that Firefox uses when you use CSS3 resize attr. Where I can find it? I'm quite sure it should be somewhere inside omni.ja, but there's a bunch of files, and files that have "resize" in their names are not what I'm looking for.

Any other alternatives are welcome.

Comment: can you post the icon you are looking for?

Comment: It's a pity that downvotes can't be cast on comments...

Comment: It can be.. on questions though.. Sorry I was trying to provide some help..

Comment: @KAD, please note that if I can post the icon, I have the icon and I don't need to ask for the icon. And I need the original icon, not a copy-and-paste from a screenshot. You want to see the icon? Please open Stackoverflow on Firefox and start another comment...

Comment: I ain't sayin that you screen shot the icon to crop it and use it, I don't have currently firefox installed and I am in an environment where I am not authorized to install it.. That's why i wanted a screen shot of the icon you need.. Anyway as for alternatives, check if this would suit you [resize-icon-font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/resize-small/)